# Post array from form to update mysql table

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have a form which I use to update stock levels in a mysql table. The three fields I post  are:

```
lst_product_id[]
txt_quantity[]
txt_cost[]
```

I can do this easily enough to update one product, however, I would like to be able to update more than one product at a time from the form by adding some more input fields.

To do this, I added another row of  three input fields (same as above) and put the [] square brackets behind all six to create an array.

This is where it all goes pear shaped, can anyone show me how to pick up the array when I post to the insert page and and update the table.

I am using the mysqli extension and am really lost here. Thank's in advance.
David

Comment: I don't have an code to show as I am stumped,i think I need to kick off with something along the lines of foreach($_POST['lst_product_id'] as $value)then somehow assign the next field to the array etc.Then I suspect I would need to count the amount of records loop to update.I could do with a simple example

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. Here is a simple example as requested that will hopefully help make the connection...

```
<?php
$post = $_POST;
?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
    <input name="id[1]" value="1" />
    <input name="quantity[1]" value="2" />
    <input name="cost[1]" value="100" />
    <input name="id[3]" value="3" />
    <input name="quantity[3]" value="1" />
    <input name="cost[3]" value="250" />
    <input name="id[8]" value="8" />
    <input name="quantity[8]" value="12" />
    <input name="cost[8]" value="25" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<pre>
<?php print_r($post); ?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

After you submit the form, you will see the format of the post data you have to work with. The value put in square brackets [] should be the id so that you can match up the cost and quantity correctly. Something like so...

```
foreach ($post['id'] as $id) {
    $cost = $post['cost'][$id];
    $quantity = $post['quantity'][$id];

    //do something with each
}
```

Comment: Thank's Marc, I will have a go at this and let you know how I get on,I'm going to stay at this so that I can get a good understanding of arrays. David