# Foreach loop still execute after the last array is updated

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I get an error "Error: Query was empty" after completing the task instead of the echo result. I suspect that the FOREACH still attempt to execute the query even the last array is updated. Am I right?

If yes, how can I correct this?

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "$username" , "$password");
    mysql_select_db($database, $con);
?>

<?php

  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key=>$id)
  {
    $order = $_POST['order'][$key];
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `order`=$order WHERE `id` = $id");
  }
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
     {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
       echo "<div class=\"result\">**1 record updated**</div>";         
?>
```

Many thanks

More information about the form posting these value : [Create array from form and update mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391716/create-array-from-form-and-update-mysql/17392552#17392552)

Comment: At what point did you populate `$sql`? Not in the above code... That's the empty query which is causing errors.

Comment: At a minimum, you must protect `$id` against sql injection. If it is an integer expected, do `$id = intval($id)`

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` looks like one more id then oder

Comment: !mysql_query($sql,$con) but where are you settting $sql?

Comment: I have just updated the question with the content of the init file. And yes Dagon, I have several ids and orders from a form.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I will add intval($id) to and intval($order) to it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not checking your errors properly, and instead, calling mysql_query twice. Do this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key=>$id)
{
  $order = $_POST['order'][$key];
  $result = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `order`=$order WHERE `id` = $id");
  if ($result === false)
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  echo "<div class=\"result\">**1 record updated**</div>";         
}
?>
```

Obligatory notices:

- Don't' use mysql - use `mysqli` or `PDO`
- Do make sure you properly escape inputs to SQL queries. Use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: Thanks, I have used your method and added this => foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key=>$ids)
{ $id = mysql_real_escape_string(ids);..... }

Answer (score 2):

The problem could be in:

```
 if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
```

its' running mysql_query without `$sql` being defined.

Though i don't recommend putting a query inside a loop because it's a waste of memory, for your code sample - try putting `mysql_query()` inside a variable like so:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET `order`=$order WHERE `id` = $id");
```

Comment: Thanks! But wonder why it still updates the table even without the $sql=

Answer (score 1):

1. You have excluded query execution from loop.
2. You *haven't defined* `$sql` anywhere, so it is threated as `empty string`.

Use this:

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key => $id)
{
    $order = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['order'][$key], $con);
    $id    = mysql_real_escape_string($id, $con);

    $sql   = "UPDATE table SET `order` = $order WHERE `id` = $id";

    if(!mysql_query($sql, $con))die(mysql_error());
}      
?>
```

**NOTE:** [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

**NOTE:** Your code is vulnurable to [***SQL-Injection***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You may read solution suggestions in this question: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

In other condition, have you check your connection before?
If it's okay try this

```
<?php
  foreach ($_POST['id'] as $key=>$id)
  {
    $order = $_POST['order'][$key];
    $query = "UPDATE table SET `order`=$order WHERE `id` = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());

  }
    if (!$result)
     {
       die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
     }
       echo "<div class=\"result\">**1 record updated**</div>";         
?>
```